# How does the Push Notifications work in WooCommerce Coupons?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, push-notification

While creating a new coupon in WooCommerce, there is an option to enable "Push Notification".

[image: Push Notification]

I understand what a push notification is, but curious to how it works. Can it be modified to send at a desired time.